# Why can't this Powershell command be executed within Jenkins?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, powershell-2.0, jenkins-plugins

I have a simple powershell command to open a web application, and then input the quick-keys required to close it:

```
#Open Application in Browser
Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("http://UrlPath")
$ie.visible = $true

#Quick key to exit application
sleep 15
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{X}")
```

This code executes with no issue when I use powershell ISE outside Jenkins. But When I try to execute the code using the Powershell plugin, or using a batch file command within Jenkins to call the .ps1 file, it will always return the following errors.

[Screenshot of errors returned by Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz8qy.jpg)

I'm using a virtual machine at work so at first I thought that was the issue. But I get the same results when using my home PC too. Any suggestions? I think the problem is permission based I'm not sure where to look to solve it.

The Powershell ISE I use outside jenkins is 32-bit, version 2.0

Comment: Is Jenkins running as a service?

Comment: Yes. A windows service

Comment: Have you tried configuring DCOM to allow the user running the Jenkins service to create a COM Object of IE ? (How to do is explained in the first response of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750928/how-to-uniquely-identify-an-internet-explorer-window-running-in-session-0)

Comment: @GzehNiert's answer makes more sense than what I was about to suggest. Give it a try and let us know :)

Comment: Managed to find DCOM and followed these instruction but errors still persist on Jenkins. I don't think this would solve my Sendkeys errors anyway. They are probably both related to a common issue. I just wish I knew what it was.

Comment: I don't think you can use SendKeys in non-interactive mode, because sending a key is an interaction.

Comment: Are you sure? I think I can find a work around with that anyway, but I definitely need to use the COM objects.