# Error creating a powershell COM object in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, automation, automated-tests

I want to create a COM object, internet explorer application.
The following code works fine in PowerShell ISE (32 bit):

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
```

But, when I try running it on Jenkins Windows server (using either the powershell plugin or calling the PS1 with a batch file), I get the following error.

```
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\Jenkins Test
[Jenkins Test] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson3148932824880446098.ps1'"
New-Object : Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the
following error: 80004005.
At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson3148932824880446098.ps1:1 char:17
+ $ie = New-Object <<<<  -com InternetExplorer.Application
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I'm using a VM at work (Server 2003). I'm not sure if this is an issue with my server permissions or if these are interactive commands being used with a non-interactive device. Can anyone help?

Comment: The "working code" and error do not match? Are you trying to draw a comparison based on COM objects?

Comment: How is this different from [the question you posted yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472969/why-cant-this-powershell-command-be-executed-within-jenkins)?

Comment: Sorry, pasted in the wrong error code. Fixed it now. I just want to focus on COM object error.

Comment: 80004005 is a rather generic error. Do you see anything related in the Jenkins or Windows logs?

Comment: There is nothing about it in the logs. They just report the code was executed successfully, despite the errors.

Comment: Please run this command on the failing machine and post the output:  `get-childitem -recurse "REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"`.   Also check if the file `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE` exists.

Comment: Hi. This code just returns an error saying it cannot find the path because it doesn't exist. The file is located in that folder.